# SQLite3-File: grep: "binary file matches" - how do I get the text from BLOB?

Tags: sqlite

I have a .db-file which is a sqlite3-file. When I type

```
grep -iR "textToSearch" *
```

I get the result

```
Binary file Cache.db matches
```

But when I look into the file (e.g. with Navicat), I only see BLOBs. How do I get the clear text to see what surrounds "textToSearch"?

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT CAST(MyColumn AS TEXT) FROM MyTable WHERE MyColumn LIKE '%textToSearch%'
```

Comment: isn't it possible to do it via grep? It's a file with about 10 tables, each with ~ 20 columns...

Answer (score 0):

Just in case: `grep -a` works too.
From the help:
 -a, --text                equivalent to --binary-files=text